# Handling post messages without model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am wondering if its possible to catch a Post action without a Model.
I need this because i want an Admin to assign user-roles to specific users.
This happens in a view with checkboxes for every role (because it is possible to have multiple roles)

I can easily make a model with All roles as a bool and let that do the trick.
But i'd rather automatically generate based on what roles are available.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could accept two variables in your Action, a string for the UserName, and a List representing the Role enumeration identifiers or names to assign.

For example:

```
public ActionResult AssignRoles(string UserName, List<int> Roles)
{  }
```

You would need to make sure that the View is marking up the Checkbox names using one of the collection tricks, Phil Haack has an excellent article here about this.

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Coincidentally i was just doing that haha. just left my question open to pick best practice.

Comment: Anyone know any possibility to bind to a dictionary?

Comment: I don't see any problem not using it unless you want your entire solution to follow an ultra-strict MVVM, better to use the right tool for the job I reckon. For your dictionary you might like to search for binding against a List of KeyValuePairs and check out the BindPrefix attribute.